# Javascript - Read value of a JSON property, if that key doesn't exist return null, in a single line

Tags: javascript, python, json

Let me give a python analogy of what I am looking for:

```
fruits_dict = {"banana": 4, "apple": 3}
num_apples = fruits_dict.get("apple", None)
num_oranges = fruits_dict.get("orange", None)
print(num_apples, num_oranges)
```

prints:
    3 None

Now in Javascript, with a similar JS object, we can use `hasOwnProperty(key)` in a `if` block

```
var fruits_obj = {"banana": 4, "apple": 3};
var num_apples = null;
if (fruits_obj.hasOwnProperty("apple")) {
    num_apples = fruits_obj["apple"];
}
var num_oranges = null;
if (fruits_obj.hasOwnProperty("orange")) {
    num_oranges = fruits_obj["orange"];
}
console.log(num_apples, num_oranges);
```

gives:
    3 null

Is there a better way? Something on the lines of python's `get` function?

Comment: Hey this answer was already given by @Razzildinho. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return it from a function, in a single line, you can use a ternary:

```
return fruits_obj.hasOwnProperty("orange") ? fruits_obj['orange'] : null;
```

Comment: Using  ECMAScript 2020 ::: 
return fruits_obj?.orange;

Answer (score 1):

There's really nothing wrong with the code you have, but it would be slightly more terse to write

```
num_oranges = ("orange" in fruits_obj) && fruits_obj.orange || null;
```

This would also find a property called "orange" in the object's prototype chain, if that's important (probably not). Also, note that

```
num_oranges = fruits_obj.orange;
```

will assign `undefined` to `num_oranges` if there's no "oranges" property, and for many practical purposes `undefined` and `null` are interchangeable. (For example, `undefined` == `null` is `true`.)

Comment: wow! nice. The `dot` notation seems great, guess I would use that. Should have tested that before asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var fruits_obj = {"banana": 4, "apple": 3};

var num_apples = fruits_obj.hasOwnProperty("apple") ? fruits_obj["apple"] : null;
var num_oranges = fruits_obj.hasOwnProperty("orange") ? fruits_obj["orange"] : null;

console.log(num_apples, num_oranges);
```

If you want to create a function like python `get` it could be something like the following:

```
var getProp = function(object, key, default){
    return object.hasOwnProperty(key) ? object[key] : default;
};

var num_oranges = getProp(fruits_obj, "orange", null);
```

Comment: exactly. This is what am looking for. Plus the dot notation returning `undefined` as told by @Pointy is also a great suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a dynamic get in your prototype object.

```
get: function(key) {
    if (typeof this[key] == 'undefined') return null;
    return this[key]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use JavaScript [**conditional (ternary) operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

This operator is used as a shortcut for the `if statement`.

**Syntax :**

```
condition ? expr1 : expr2
```

If condition is `true`, the operator returns the value of `expr1`; otherwise, it returns the value of `expr2`.

```
var res = fruits_obj.hasOwnProperty("orange") ? fruits_obj['orange'] : null
```